# How to get the revenue with admob adds in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have implement admob for google ads.But How can I display only particular adds only in my BannerView (Which is given by client) and one more thing, How Client will get the revenue by using this ads?

Should I add any account details for that?

I understood the tutorials about adds.But I am confused by these things? can anyone clarify these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload application on Appstore, please use Admob Id of Client's account. In case if your monthly revenue reaches more than 100$, Google will paid you 21st of every month.

When you select / create ads in google, you can select different category for ads as well.

Comment: ok but how can we add particular adds??